# How to get a specific data from a look up website

Tags: java, web

I'm totally new to this section of networking with java.
What I'm trying to do is that, I want the user to add machine type and serial and when he press a button, this will extract the machine expiration date, model and country from a website and then put this data in a txt file automatically.
I'd like as well that the browser to be hidden but don't know how to do it.
I will really appreciate your help.
As well I would prefer to use JTextArea with a vertically  only scroll pane to allow the user adding more than one machine (let's say 50 machines) at once , but as well, I don't know how to make the program read the type and serial from this JTextArea separatly
Here is my current code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.net.URI;

public class PEW_Frame extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField type;
private JTextField serial;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                PEW_Frame frame = new PEW_Frame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public PEW_Frame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    type = new JTextField();
    type.setBounds(121, 27, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(type);
    type.setColumns(10);

    serial = new JTextField();
    serial.setBounds(121, 72, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(serial);
    serial.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(34, 30, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("New label");
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(34, 75, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
            String getType = type.getText();
            String getSerial = serial.getText();
            //String getType1 = type1.getText();
            //String getSerial1 = serial1.getText();
            String url = "https://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/wlup?type="+getType+"&serial="+getSerial;
            //String url1 = "https://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/wlup?type="+getType1+"&serial="+getSerial1;
            try {
                if (getType.isEmpty() || getSerial.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                d.browse(new URI(url));
                //d.browse(new URI(url1));
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You must select SLA and period","Error !", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(176, 189, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

    //type1 = new JTextField();
    //type1.setBounds(229, 27, 86, 20);
    //contentPane.add(type1);
    //type1.setColumns(10);

    //serial1 = new JTextField();
    //serial1.setBounds(229, 72, 86, 20);
    //contentPane.add(serial1);
    //serial1.setColumns(10);
}
}
```

Comment: Open the url in the background and read the content of the page to extract the data you want. Be warned though that this approach is fragile since the structure of the page might be changed by whoever runs that site and the data might not be found anymore. If you can get access to some webservice I'd suggest you use that.

Comment: As Thomas said, the approach is fragile. If you really want to do it that way consider using a library like jsoup (http://jsoup.org)

Comment: Thank you for the hints  but I'm still don't get it, I'm not expert with java at all, just try to learn it myself, I thought about saving the website itself as txt (not the html code), then the saved txt file can be scanned for the data I need. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can get some help from the following example:

https://github.com/dotKom/OnlineGuru/blob/master/onlineguru/src/main/java/no/ntnu/online/onlineguru/plugin/plugins/middag/UpdateMenu.java#L40

```
public void run() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // This posts the required fields to the sit.no RESTful menu api.
    try {
        // Prepare post data
        String postData = "diner="+ kantine.toLowerCase() +"&trigger=single";

        // Open connection
        java.net.URL url = new URL(URLTEXT);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        // Write the post data
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(postData);
        wr.flush();

        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        wr.close();
        rd.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Failed to get JSON data from "+URLTEXT, e.getCause());
    }

    // Get the html content into a clean string
    String json = new String(sb);
    json = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(json);
    String html = json.split(":")[1].replaceAll("^\"|\"}$", "");

    // Traverse html with Jsoup
    String menu = findMenuItems(html);

    setMenu(kantine, menu);
}
```

Comment: This link, especially code example (not very professional: e. g. closing resources inside `try`, or relying on presence of `":"` separator in response, and that html will always be the first and the only element in json) doesn't clarify anything nor helps OP to solve his problem.

Comment: Thank you for the hints  but I'm still don't get it, I'm not expert with java at all, just try to learn it myself, I thought about saving the website itself as txt (not the html code), then the saved txt file can be scanned for the data I need. Is it possible?